# Pesquisa por API / JSON - Latam e Gol (Power BI)

Tags: python, json, r, powerbi, powerquery

Bom Dia!

Galera, estou montando um dashboard no Power BI, e preciso vincular ele ao site de rasteamento de cargas da Gollog e Latam.

Já tenho o link para pesquisa do webservice, porem não sei como vincular essa pesquisa a minha base de dados do Power BI. Preciso que ele rode uma pesquisa para cada linha da minha base de dados, onde estão os AWBs a serem pesquisados.

link:

https://api-golcargo.gollog.com.br/Api/PartnerIntegration/UCAS
http://integracliente.soa.lancargo.com/lancargo/wteService?wsdl

Comment: https://api-golcargo.gollog.com.br/Api/PartnerIntegration/UCAS Não usa esse não, foi feito para migrar a plataforma deles da UNISYS. Usa esse aqui, https://api-golcargo.gollog.com.br/docs/v1/index

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acredito que no Power BI não é possível rodar um serviço desses. Acredito que o ideal seria criar um serviço a parte que consuma os dados de sua base, consulte a API e gere outra base de modo que haja relacionamento entre as duas bases.

Com python é bem fácil montar o consumo de API's.